# Running Ubuntu on Asus UX303LA

Tags: 14.04, hardware, asus, thinkpad

I've been looking for a Laptop for school and stumbled across the Asus UX303LA since Lenovo doesn't bother using decent displays in their beginner to semi-professional Thinkpads.

I'm probably getting [this](http://www.conrad.de/ce/de/product/1221168/?gclid=CIqXidDf18ACFZTLtAodLSIA6g&insert_kz=VQ&hk=SEM&WT.srch=1&WT.mc_id=google_pla&s_kwcid=AL!222!3!48490274937!!!g!!&ef_id=VBDXWgAABZiukv7D:20140910225730:s) configuration.(i5-4210U, 500GB HDD,Intel graphics 4400HD,13.3" 1600 x 900)
I heard from several people that Ubuntu works out-of-the-box on the antecessor UX32LA without major problems.(Only things like brightness control need a little hand work). But I'm not sure about the compatibility of the UX303LA.

I want to run Windows 7/8 along with Ubuntu 14.04.1 LTS and do mostly programming (webdesign) and browsing, no gaming or video editing and therefore no external graphics needed (maybe a little photoshop or Gimp but I think the intel graphics will be sufficent). Most important for me is the low weight and the long runtime.

My second choice would have been the Lenovo Thinkpad S440 but the awful screen keeps me from buying it. I chose the 500Gb model of the Asus so I could exchange the HDD with a cheap 256Gb SSD.

If anyone had experience with Ubuntu on this laptop or suggestions for similar laptops which you would recommend instead I'd be very grateful. (Please consider that I live in Germany and therefore would prefer Laptops available in Europe)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found this thread by googling, so I hope this answer might inform someone. Running the risk of necromancing, FWIW we have several Asus UX303LA (and UX303UB for that matter) in the office, and they all run just fine under Ubuntu and ElementaryOS in recent versions (we have 18.04 and 18.10 atm), and they have been since 2015.

No apparent issues, even screen brightness keys worked out of the box.